# How do I pass an array of strings to a ruby method that wants the strings but not in an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I have an array of strings (actually file names), something like

```
filenames = ['file1.jpg', 'file2.jpg', 'file3.jpg']
```

The method I am calling expects something like

```
images = Magick::ImageList.new("image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png")
```

but if I call as below, I am actually passing an array.

```
images = Magick::ImageList.new(filenames)
```

How do I unwrap the contents of the array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do as below using **splat opearator(*)** :

```
 images = Magick::ImageList.new(*filenames)
```

As **@Stefan** mentioned the documentation link for the same [**Array to Arguments Conversion**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion)

Comment: Here's a link to the documentation: [Array to Arguments Conversion](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion)

Comment: @Stefan I have added it to my answer... Thanks for the suggestion for further improvement....